# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'type' decorator python не работает декоратор должным образом

Tags: python, классы

```
class decor(object):
    def __init__(self, argum):
        self.arg = 2 * argum

@decor
class person:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age

pers = person(15)

print(pers.age)
```

декоратор должен увеличивать аргументы декорированного класса в 2 раза

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?

```
def decorator(cls):
    class T(cls):
        def __init__(_, *args, **kwargs):
            args = (arg * 2 for arg in args)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return T


@decorator
class person:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age = age
```